# what is the meaning of $(this) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have following code for Calendar Pop-Up which is working fine

```
<input type="text" value="12/01/2010"  readonly="readonly" name="start_date_1" id="start_date_1" disabled="disabled"/>
  <img src="/images/calendar_date_select/calendar.gif" onclick="new CalendarDateSelect( $(this).previous(), {popup:'force', year_range:10} );" class="calender_image" alt="Calendar"/>
```

but what I want is my calendar pop up will remain disabled initially and after clicking on Edit button only it should get open. I use `disabled="disabled"` but it's not working due to the  `popup:'force'`

So I write following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   function disable_pop_up(){
     if (edit==true)
       new CalendarDateSelect( $(this).previous(), {popup:'force', year_range:10} );
     else
       return false;
   }
</script>


<input type="text" value="12/01/2010"  readonly="readonly" name="start_date_1" id="start_date_1" disabled="disabled"/>
  <img src="/images/calendar_date_select/calendar.gif" onclick="disable_pop_up()" class="calender_image" alt="Calendar"/>
```

Of course JavaScript fails as expected, so my question is what should I write in a `disable_pop_up()` to accomplish it?

**EDITED **

My problem is get solved by sending `$(this)` as an argument

```
  function disable_pop_up(cal, id){
     disable = document.getElementById(id).disabled
     if (disable==true)
       return false;
     else
       new CalendarDateSelect( cal.previous(), {popup:'force', year_range:10} );
  } 

  onclick="disable_pop_up($(this), 'start_date_1'"
```

But still my question remains same why can't I write something like `$("#start_date_1")` in my JavaScript function?

Comment: Strictly spoken $(this) *in javascript* has no meaning at all. It's a jquery construct.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) refers to the HTML element of the calling function.

Comment: so can i replace it with some other code in javascript function given above?

Comment: My Javascript is rusty and I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. All I know is what $(this) refers to. Sorry.

Comment: "this" doesn't refer to the instance of the CalendarDateSelect, in the first snippet it refers to the img element (the one you clicked on) and in the second it refers to the window element.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right, it refers to the HTML element of the calling function. Modified to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a shorthand for the `jQuery` function. This will only work if you have the jquery library loaded in your page.

Answer (score 0):

in your first example, `$(this).previous()` is going to refer to the input, so if you want to change your function, try

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   function disable_pop_up(){
     if (edit==true)
       new CalendarDateSelect( $("#start_date_1"), {popup:'force', year_range:10} );
     else
       return false;
   }
</script>
```

p.s. the [$ function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), is shorthand for the main jQuery function